# `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Tags: rust, bigdecimal

I need to use the `bigdecimal` crate, so I include it in my dependencies in `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies]
bigdecimal = "0.1.0"
```

While writing the code, I get the following error:

```
bigdecimal::BigDecimal, which does not implement the 'Copy' trait
```

For example:

```
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let val_1 = BigDecimal::from_str("1").unwrap();
    let val_2 = BigDecimal::from_str("2").unwrap();

    let result = val_2/val_1;

    println!("Test 1 {} ", result);
    println!("Test 2 {} ", val_2);
}
```

When execute the error message below will appear:

```
----- move occurs because `val_2` has type `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

The only way I can solve it is by declaring again val_2 before the print statement

```
println!("Test 1 {} ", result);
let val_2 = BigDecimal::from_str("2").unwrap();
println!("Test 2 {} ", val_2);
```

Is there any other efficient way to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can just take references:

```
let result = &val_2/&val_1;
```

to use the proper version of division: `impl<'a, 'b> Div<&'b BigDecimal> for &'a BigDecimal` where your code currently uses `impl Div<BigDecimal> for BigDecimal` (you can find both in https://docs.rs/bigdecimal/0.1.0/bigdecimal/struct.BigDecimal.html as well as many other versions). If the difference doesn't make sense to you, you really need to read [References and Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.0/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) first (and the `'a` `'b` parts can probably be ignored for now).

In other cases, you may need calls like `val2.clone()` to make a copy explicitly.

For why `BigDecimal` can't be `Copy` (then it would make copies automatically whenever needed), see https://github.com/rust-num/num/issues/191:

> As a rule of thumb, only primitives and aggregates composed of just primitives can implement `Copy`. So for instance, `PrimInt` does implement `Copy`, but `BigInt` has a `Vec` underneath, so it can only be explicitly cloned.